# docker build fails in jhipster

Tags: docker, jhipster

Can someone point me in the right direction for the error below?
I have DOCKER_HOST set (192.168.99.100:2376)

I entered the following command on my windows box:

```
mvnw package -Pprod docker:build -DskipTests -e
```

All works fine but, when building the image, I am getting the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.10:build (default-cli) on project
>   truup: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: The server failed to
>   respond with a valid HTTP response -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.10:build
>   (default-cli) on project truup: Exception caught
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what described at [ClientProtocolException (Windows 10 using Docker Toolbox)](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/177).

Check these environment variables:

```
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
set DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\myuserhere.docker\machine\machines\default
```

Comment: Thank you gile!!!  you recommended changes solved the issue.  Again, your help has been appreciated.